# Sitecore doesn't add the indexed field with Traditional Chinese & Simplified Chinese postfix on the Azure custom index

Tags: indexing, azure-search

I am doing a POC in **Sitecore.Net 9.2 vanilla setup**  for enabling the **Traditional Chinese and Simplified Chinese** in the CMS and looking for how can I perform the Azure search for the content in **zh-HK and zh-CN**.

**What I Performed?**
I have added new languages **zh-HK & zh-CN** in the Sitecore under **/System/Languages** and created the item languages versions in **en(default), th-TH, zh-HK and zh-CN**, published the content and indexed onto Azure Search.

**What Issue I faced?**  -
I can see from my custom index's fields tab that the field let's say **Title** is created for 2 languages version i.e. **title_s, title_s_en and title_s_th** but not created for **zh-HK and zh-CN** and obviously there is no could analyzer for **zh-HK and zh-CN**.

Did anyone face this issue? It seems very simple setup with Sitecore but things are not working at my end. Please let me know in case I am doing something wrong here? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check your schema contains the entry for *_t_zh in it? Please check that once

Comment: After the some config modifications, my search index schema has *_t_zh and keeps zh-Hant.lucene cloud analyzer which works for Traditional Chinese but It can't work for Simplied Chinese because it uses different cloudAnalyzer i.e. zh-Hans.lucene .. how create different language specific field for zh-CN and set it's unique analyzer

Comment: Can you try something from this blog : https://www.searchstax.com/blog/traditional-chinese-indexing-solr-searchstax/

Comment: I have already seen this blog, it didn't help... Since I am using Azure Search where things are different

Comment: Posting to help others - As per Sitecore Support, Sitecore has bug and given the below work around

Answer (score 1):

Replying to my question and sharing my chat with Sitecore Support Team. Therefore It could help others  -

As per Sitecore Support, Sitecore 9.2 has a bug and provides the work around mentioned below for the issue asked above,

1. Change in the cloud analyzer id from "cn" to "zh". Hence, the language specific field will be created in your search index.
2. Currently only one Cloud Analyzer either "Hans" or "Hant" can be set via Sitecore Config for all Chinese Regional Language. It seems another bug to me. The one in need, should seek for the HotFix from Sitecore to resolve this bug.